# Batch file for creating rar

Tags: batch-file

I am really new to batch files so please bear with me. I want to make a batch file that can zip folders inside the main folder to one individual win-rar file.

I have the following line which is making the main folder rar but i need only the folders inside the main folder to be archived.

```
SET WINRAR="F:\Program Files\WinRAR"

%WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe a -ep1 "F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test.rar" "F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test"
```

What I need is to make the folders inside the test folder as individual rar files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the folders to create individual rar files

```
SET WINRAR="F:\Program Files\WinRAR"

    for /D %%f in ("F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test\*") do (
        %WINRAR%\RAR.exe a -ep1 -r0 "F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test\%%~nxf.rar" "%%f"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for that its working fine. I have one more query like my folder names will be like 2009-558789,2009-457896, I want to rename them as 558789,457896 like that i want to remove the 2009- from 2009-558789 using a seperate batch file

Comment: Try `for /d %%f in ("d:..wherever..\2009-*") do cmd /v:on /c "set d=%%~nxf&& echo ren "%%f" "!d:~5!" "` keeping spaces as is. If the result is correct, remove `echo` to do the rename

Comment: Hi MC ND i am running this as below SET WINRAR="F:\Program Files\WinRAR"

for /d %%f in ("F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test\2010\2010-*") do cmd /v:on /c "set d=%%~nxf&& echo ren "%%f" "!d:~5!" "       but nothing gets changed and not able to figure out the error

Comment: You are asigning the content of a variable. Not running the indicated command. The line in previous comment is to be included in a batch file as is (changing the path). Or you can replace all the %% with a single % an run from command line.

Comment: I have tried as per your suggestion i am getting the following text as output on screen                                              F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop>cmd /v:on /f "set d=2010-5606421&& echo re
n "F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test\2010\2010-5606421" "!d:~5!" "
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

Comment: Should be cmd /v:on `/c`

Comment: Hi as per my understanding what ever output i am getting is not replacing the folder name 2009-123456 if iam wrong dont mind iam running on the command prompt it is giving as below                                       F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop>cmd /v:on /c "set f=2010-5606422&& echo ren "F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test\2010-5606422" "!d:~5!" "5!" "
ren "F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test\2010-5606422" "!d:~5!" "5!"

Comment: Ok. Copy and paste, into command line,  as is, the following command `@for /d %f in ("F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test\20*-*") do @cmd /v:on /c "@set d=%~nxf&& @echo ren "%f" "!d:~5!" "` this should show only the commands it will run if echo is not present. If the output is ok, remove @echo and directories will be renamed. To insert the command in a batch file, all % refering to variable f needs to be doubled.

Comment: hi this is more interesting and i want to know how to use the regular expressions in this for renaming the folders as i have the folder name some thing like cnf-01-2012-6374375-6374969_6374970 and i have to rename it as 2012-6374970

Comment: No a regular expression. Just string management over the variable arguments. The command was just taking the name of the folder (`%~nxf`), asignin it to a variable (d) so we could get a substring from fifth position (`!d:~5!`). If all your folders are as your sample, `!d:~8,12!` will do the work

Comment: I am trying with the above but i have a doubt like my input is cnf-01-2012-6374375-6374969_6374970   and my ouput should be 3rd string(2012-) and 6th string(6374970) i don't want the text in the middle of it. but i am not getting that

Comment: `!d:~7,5!!d:~28,7!` or search this site to do string management / splitting in batch files. Maybe you need something more elaborated.

Comment: can u give me the website name